# How to pass an object instance to a jinja html template

Tags: python, jinja2

My class looks like this

```
class Foo():
    x = attrib()
    y = attrib()


f = Foo(x=1, y=2)
```

My template looks like

```
<html>
<body>
 <span>{{x}}</span> -> instead of this I want to use foo.x
 <span>{{y}}</span> -> instead of this I want to use foo.y
</body>
</html>
```

I use `template.render(**attr.asdict(f))` to render it.
Instead I want to just pass `template.render(f)` and use `{{f.x}}` and `{{f.y}}`

Is there a way to do this?
I keep running into the error

```
vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using

```
Template.render(dict(foo=f))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `template.render` needs to know what to call your variables. For that reason, it accepts either a dict of `"varname": "value"`, or keyword arguments, like `render(x=f.x, y=f.y)`. This is exactly what your `**attr.asdict(f)` expression evaluates to; but it would work just as well if you didn't include the `**`.

To solve your problem, simply use a keyword argument: `template.render(f=f)`. This also allows you to rename the variable: if you want to use `foo.x` in template, call `template.render(foo=f)`